# Create compile-time constants with first N bits set

Tags: c++, c++17

In C++17, is there are way to generate at compile-time a constant with the first N bits set?

In pseudocode, I am looking for something like:

```
constexpr uint32_t MY_CONSTANT = setBits<2>();
```

Would be equivalent to:

```
constexpr uint32_t MY_CONSTANT = 0b11;
```

In other words, given a compile-time constant N, return a compile-time constant M where bits 0 to (N-1) are 1 (set).

Comment: You could take an unsigned -1 (all bits set) and just shift away the unwanted bits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's a ready made function for it in the standard library (although `std::bitset::set` is `constexpr` since C++23). You could make your own though:

```cpp
template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr T setBits() {
    if constexpr (N == sizeof(unsigned long long) * CHAR_BIT) return ~T{};
    else return static_cast<T>((1ull << N) - 1);
}

constexpr auto MY_CONSTANT = setBits<std::uint32_t, 2>();
```

Example for `setBits<std::uint8_t, 2>()`:

```
   0b00000001
<<          2
-------------
=  0b00000100

   0b00000100
-           1
-------------
=  0b00000011
```

Or negate `0` to get all bits set and right shift away all but `N` bits:

```cpp
template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr T setBits() {
    if constexpr (N == 0) return 0;
    else return ~T{} >> (sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT - N);
}
```

Comment: Note that this won't work if N equals the bitdepth of a ULL. It'd be easy to do an `if constexpr` around this for that special case.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, both version has those edge cases. Will add a check!